# Вывести изображение товара

Tags: drupal

использую drupal7 + ubercart. подскажите пожалуйста как в node--product.tpl.php вывести изображение товара. причем вывести таким образом чтобы при клике по миниатюре открывалась изображение в полном размере(это мне нужно для того чтобы позже навесить fancybox)

вообще я сделал dprint_r($node) и узнал все нужные мне пересенные($id, $title, $price и т.д.). но с выводом изображения товара засада. помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Используйте модуль devel для просмотра состава переменных.